# Toolbox Control Installer (TCI) in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, toolbox

In Visual Studio 2015 and earlier there was an easy way to add a custom control to the Toolbox by adding a registry key in

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\XX.0\ToolboxControlsInstaller

It seems not working anymore in Visual Studio 2017, someone know how to achieve the same goal?

Comment: read this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2813/cant-find-registry-entries-for-visual-studio-2017.html

Comment: Thanks, it seems that some other people found the same issue than me, without a cleaned solution :(

Comment: This new VS release has decoupled itself from most of heavy dependencies on registry and so on. Either you open a Connect issue to ask or open a support case.

Comment: It seems that it works by adding the "ToolboxControlsInstaller" registry subkey in
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxxxx, anyway I'm going to open a support case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from VS2017, Microsoft wants to reduce the registry impact (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/breaking-changes-2017)) and each instance (Professional, Community, etc...) installed on the same machine for the same user has its own settings.

In short:

- If you need to register a single component, you can continue to add the ToolboxControlsInstaller subkey in the registry
- If you need to register a lot of components, the suggested approach is to [use VSIX and PKGDEF](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6388bfbb-732d-42a3-884b-f3032756c800/configure-toolbox-using-pkgdef-file?forum=vsx) for leaving the registry cleaned.

BTW both in registry and %VSAppDataVisualStudio% folder, the new subkeys/subfolders are created for each Visual Studio instance.
[image]